# JWT tokens refresh and access best practice for browsers and mobile apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I am trying to create an auth server with nodejs and mongodb. I am trying to implement JWT auth with access and refresh tokens. I have read that you should store the access token in localstorage or memory and then pass the refresh token with an httponly cookie to protect against XSS attacks. The problem with the http only cookie is that you cant use this with things like mobile apps. The whole point of creating a rest api is so you can access the data from anywhere.

So what is the best way to handle different storage requirements of different devices and keeping them secure. Is there a good solution for either storing the refresh token on the browser without a httponly cookie? Should I just use localStorage even though its vulnerable to XSS attacks?  Or do I need to create different endpoints for mobile and browser. Is there an industry standard for this? There is a lot of talk about using JWT but there does not seam to be a clear explanation of how to securely implement access and refresh tokens for mobile and browser apps alike.

Comment: Well, the problem you are trying to solve with Strict SameSite HttpOnly cookies doesn't exist in mobile apps - mobile apps are sandboxed. There's no concept of other webpages (or apps in this context) being able to access your LocalStorage for example.

Comment: Each client has its own requirements for storing data like this. In browser clients, you would store it in LocalStorage. In mobile you would use something like KeyChain service for iOS.

When you go to make a request to your server, then its an HTTP request and you can add whatever cookies you want to it

Comment: @nbokmans I am aware of this that is why I asked the question. What would be the best way to handle the different storage requirements of devices on the back end because in non browser devices there are no httponly cookies.

Comment: @Literphor This is why I asked the question. What is the best way to handle the differences in storage requirements with keeping the tokens secure. Do I need to create 2 different endpoints for browser and app. Or should I just use localStorage and do my best to prevent xss attacks.